# Evaluate $\iint_{\partial[0,a]^3}\vec F\cdot\vec n\,\mathrm dS$ where $\vec F = 4zx\,\vec\imath - y^2\,\vec\jmath + yz\,\vec k$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Evaluate $\iint\vec F\cdot\vec n\,\mathrm dS$ where $\vec F = 4zx\,\vec\imath - y^2\,\vec\jmath + yz\,\vec k$, $S$ is the surface of the cube bounded by $x=0$ ,$x=a$, $y =0$, $y=a$, $z=0$, $z=a$.

$$\iint_S\vec F\cdot\vec n\,\mathrm dS = \iint_S \frac{F\cdot\nabla(S)}{|\nabla(S)\cdot\vec p|}\,\mathrm dA$$

where $\mathrm dA$ is the element of the shadow region of the surface element $\mathrm dS$, $\vec p$ is the unit normal vector to $\mathrm dA$

$$\iint_S\vec F\cdot\vec n\,\mathrm dS = \iint_S\frac{\vec F\cdot\vec k}{\left|\vec k\cdot\vec p\right|}\,\mathrm dA$$

Then

$$\iint_S\vec F\cdot\vec n\,\mathrm dS= \iint_S\frac{yz}{\left|\vec k\cdot\vec k\right|}\,\mathrm dA= \iint_S yz\,\mathrm dA= \iint_S ay\,\mathrm dA$$

Then I'm getting the answer $\frac{a^4}2$ and since there are $6$ surfaces so the total flux should be $3a^4$.
But the answer is given $\frac{3a^4}2$.
Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: You cannot expect that the flux is the same for all faces. – I think that the poser of the problem had another kind of solution in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flux is not the same for all faces. For example, if $z=0$ then the versor is $n=(0,0,-1)$ and
$$\int_{x=0}^a\int_{y=0}^a F(x,y,0)\cdot (0,0,-1) dxdy=0.$$
In a similar way we got zero for $x=0$ and $y=0$. For $x=a$,
$$\int_{y=0}^a\int_{z=0}^a F(a,y,z)\cdot (1,0,0) dydz=4a\int_{z=0}^a zdz=2a^4.$$
For $y=a$,
$$\int_{x=0}^a\int_{z=0}^a F(x,a,z)\cdot (0,1,0) dxdz=-a^4.$$
For $z=a$,
$$\int_{x=0}^a\int_{y=0}^a F(x,y,a)\cdot (0,0,1) dxdy=a\int_{z=0}^a ydy=\frac{a^4}{2}.$$ 
Therefore the total flux is $3a^4/2$.

The evaluation of the total flux is much easier if we apply the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Mathematical_statement): the flux of $F$  through the surface of the cube is the integral of $\text{div}(F)=4z-2y+y=4z-y$ over the whole cube:
$$\iiint_{[0,a]^3}(4z-y)dxdydz=4a^2\int_0^a z dz-a^2\int_0^a y dy=2a^4-\frac{a^4}{2}=\frac{3a^4}{2}.$$

Comment: Yea, I forgot to take the directions. So total flux should be zero. I think the answer in the answer key is given taking only three surfaces into considerations.

Comment: Yea, it is easy to calculate by divergence theorem. But what if I want to calculate using the formula I mentioned.

Comment: OK. Then evaluate the integral over each face of the cube and take the sum. Flux is zero over the faces $x=0$, $y=0$ and $z=0$. Three faces  still to be considered.

Comment: @Mathsaddict Check your evaluations with my edit.